# Arduino serial: Cannot allocate memory: '/dev/ttyACM0'

Tags: c, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I run a script on RPI (Raspbian GNU/Linux 11) with python 3.9.2 with following line:

```py
import serial

serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

Which raises error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '/dev/ttyACM0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 12] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

Same happens while using `screen` (v. 4.08.00):

```
~$ screen /dev/ttyACM0
[screen is terminating]
Cannot open line '/dev/ttyACM0' for R/W: Cannot allocate memory
```

I've checked if this is an issue with RPI's lack of memory, but it doesn't seem like it:

```
free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         3930028      618276     1271488       77368     2040264     3076624
```

Just to make sure I checked and it seems that Arduino's symlink is still present.

```
ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 26 18:02 usb-Arduino__www.arduino.cc__0043_85036313430351014161-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
```

When I reboot the Arduino - problem is fixed but occurs again in some time. I didn't notice pattern here, sometimes it's a month, sometimes 2 weeks...

Any ideas where should I even look to fix this?

---

OS: `Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v7l+ #1538 SMP Thu Mar 31 19:39:41 BST 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Arduino Sketch: [github](https://github.com/jakubmatyszewski/plant-room/blob/master/plant-room/MoistureSketch/MoistureSketch.ino)

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // open serial port, set the baud rate as 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  int val;
  val = analogRead(0); // connect sensor to Analog 0
  Serial.println(val); // print the value to serial port
  delay(10); // 1000 = every second
}
```

Comment: You're not showing us the full Python script, right?  How many copies of this script are running concurrently?  (You can use `ps auxw` to see.)  How long does the script run?  How many Serial objects does each script use at a time?  If it's a long running script, are you careful to close each Serial object after you are done using it?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3919

Comment: @DavidGrayson, the script runs as a cron job, which is fired each minute, whole code is in the repo: https://github.com/jakubmatyszewski/plant-room/blob/master/plant-room/plant-room.py
I will take a look more into Serial object, since maybe I'm in fact not closing it correctly, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, issue you mentioned was in the end fixed with rpi firmware update, but in this case I'm already running latest release. In fact I've run `sudo wc -l debug/usb/xhci/0000:01:00.0/devices/03/ep06/trbs` and received `32768 debug/usb/xhci/0000:01:00.0/devices/03/ep06/trbs` which is same issue as mentioned in topic you linked, however I'm not sure if cause is the same. (?)

Comment: @DavidGrayson, followup question, since I tried enclosing serial operations in context manager, hoping that this will result in proper Serial object closure, but it seems like today I encountered same error. Maybe you were referencing something else writing about closure?

Comment: Closing a serial port simply means calling the `.close()` method on it, which should free all resources allocated for it in the kernel and hopefully prevent any errors about lack of memory.  You can use the `with` keyword which helps you close the serial port more reliably.  I don't know much about "context manager".  Since you didn't answer my other questions, I have no idea how many serial ports you have open at a time so I don't know how important it is to close them.  They get closed automatically when the Python program ends anyway.

Comment: @DavidGrayson With context manager I meant that I used `with` keyword and as I mentioned, signal is called by python script run by cronjob, so it is run every minute, but after short (>1s) computation it is finished, so according to what you said the signal should be closed anyway. So in summary, there should be either 0 or 1 signal connection in any given time.
In the end I start to believe that this might be a problem within arduino memory, but the C script I run is rather simple, so I'm not sure yet what can be the failing point...
Still, thanks for your input David.